# Why was my post closed by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

I asked [a question about connnecting a printer to Google Cloud on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/720363/i-try-to-register-my-dell-c3765-printer-but-get-registration-failed-bios-is-up) and he put it on hold stating:

> Questions on Server Fault must be about **managing information
>   technology systems in a business environment**. Home and end-user
>   computing questions may be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), and questions
>   about development, testing and development tools may be asked on
>   [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

This is a network printer we’re trying to bring on-line in our subnet which is for guest purposes only.

Dell’s C3765 printer is for workgroups.

What’s not business?

Comment: Do you mean [this question on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/720363/i-try-to-register-my-dell-c3765-printer-but-get-registration-failed-bios-is-up)? It seems like the closure is correct; Server Fault is about “… managing information technology systems in a business environment.” and then the closure continues to say, “ Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User…” So perhaps that question should just be moved there?

Comment: Your original question is concerning Google Cloud printing so should be asked on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ as questions about webapps are off-topic on [su]

Answer (score 4):

Everyone makes mistakes, myself included.

This does indeed appear to be a business printer, and so I've reopened the question (and removed an inappropriate tag).

You may still want to improve the question, as it seems to be lacking sufficient detail, and [the community may still choose to close it again](https://serverfault.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: To be honest, I still think the post would be better on the [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) site since the crux of the issue seems to be focused on the web-app aspect of this setup. Definitely an edge-case here.

Comment: @JakeGould We don't look for the best fit. We look at `is it on topic`. And if it isn't, we should look at `is it a good question` and if so we can check if it fits another SE site.

Comment: Michael,  Thanks for reopening.  I really just didn't know how to reach you.  Even the comments to go to Web Apps are much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't see any obvious errors in the firewall, but I'll look again.  With respect to researching, I couldn't find anything about the error I'm currently receiving--even on the dell KB.  The only thing I noticed were some people failing to register because they didn't have google cloud enabled printers.  My printer clearly is cloud enabled (it's actually a button on the interface).